# How to pass cell selection value in button action

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have one tableview with 1 section and two rows,
and down I have one button action.

In the button action I have to check which cell is clicked because according to that cell I have to open email view for sending mail.

I created for two bool values, but It is not working properly, still my emailview get call without  cell is selected
 this code what i am doing

```
@implementation View
@synthesize Mytableview,selectedIndexPaths,value1,value2,cellselected;
BOOL values[1];



// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [Mytableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([indexPath row] == 0 && [indexPath section] == 0)
    {

        cell.textLabel.text= @"test";

        if (values[indexPath.row]) { 
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        value1=TRUE;
    }

    else if ([indexPath row] == 1 && [indexPath section] == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text= @"test";
        value2=TRUE;
    }


        return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    //[Mytableview deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    //self.cellselected = indexPath.row;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [Mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //here values is i give as array on top as BOOL values[1];i give size for it 
    values[indexPath.row] = !values[indexPath.row];

    if (values[indexPath.row]) { 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}


-(IBAction)ExportEmail
{


    if (value1==FALSE) {
        return;
    }
    else {

    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if (mailClass != nil)
{
// We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
        if ([mailClass canSendMail])
        {
            [self displayComposerSheet];
        }

    }
    }

}
```

Comment: As you are checking for FALSE, assign the other BOOL value to FALSE when you are setting one to TRUE. Like where you say `value1=TRUE` below that set `value2=FALSE`. And same goes for `value2=TRUE` set `value1=FALSE` below that line.

Answer (score 0):

Declare class veriable NSIndexPath;

```
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath;
```

Modify your didSelectRowAtIndexPath to below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [Mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //here values is i give as array on top as BOOL values[1];i give size for it 

    myIndexPath = indexPath;

    if (values[indexPath.row]) { 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

You can use that NSIndexPath in you Button's IBAction and according to index you can open up email.

```
-(IBAction)ExportEmail
{
    if(myIndexPath.row==0){
    // send mail    
    }else if(myIndexPath.row==1){
    // send mail 
    }
}
```

Comment: jay mehta i pass myindexpath in button action but hoe to know which cell is selected it still open all

Comment: What exception are you getting but? Can you paste your error or explain your problem more ?

Comment: This code will not work because the cell is not selected when you press the button inside it.

Comment: Have you tried this Code my dear friend ? myIndexPath is Class level variable once you tap on cell it will change myIndexPath value. there is no need for selecting cell while pressing that button ! Are you getting my point!